# MSAL integration Web App taking last login user details when updating records in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, msal

I am working on adal to msal migration, facing issue with while updating records, Web App is taking last logged in user details to update data. Please find my code below.

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetTokenForWebApiAsync(string resourceId2,
         string authority)
{
    IConfidentialClientApplication app = this.CreateApplication();
    AuthenticationResult authResult;

    var scopes = new[] { $"{resourceId2}/.default" };
    ////var account = await app.GetAccountAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var authres = OpenIdAuthenticationEvents.AuthenticationResult;

    try
    {
        // try to get an already cached token
        authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, authres.Account)
                              .ExecuteAsync()
                              .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
    {
        // The controller will need to challenge the user
        // including asking for claims={ex.Claims}
        throw;
    }

    return authResult;
}
```